# passing array of data from jsp to servlet

Tags: jsp

I have a form that has input field for car model and car color like following

```
<form>
  <input id="car1" name="car1" value="audi"/>
  <input id="color1" name="color1" value="red"/>
  <input id="car2" name="car2" value="honda"/>
  <input id="color2" name="color2" value="black"/>
  <input id="car3" name="car3" value="toyota"/>
  <input id="color3" name="color3" value="silver"/>
</form>
```

I need to send those input value to a servlet and maintain relationship between car and color. In order to maintain relationship between car and color, in servlet I am thinking of creating a Map object with car as key and color as value. What is the best way to send the input value and create a Map in the servlet. The other problem is the number of car and color is dynamic. In other words, I may have car1,color1,car2,color2 or car1,color1,car2,color2,car3,color3.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to call request.getParameterValues();

This returns you a map of key-values iterate over them and have the corresponding values.

Comment: If I use request.getParameterValues(), I will need to use the same name for all input related to car and do the same for input related to color. If I do this, I will loose the relationship between car and color. How do I map the right car with the right color?

Comment: I din.get you..what do you want to acheive by maintaining relation between them

Comment: See the ORM object relational mapping says that you need to have the same database column name as the request parameters as well as the bean(setters/getters) name. So for param name =username ,dbcolumn name  should be username and setUsername and getUserName as your beans.....These things may not be of some relevance in this comment but just to tell you that relation is maintained even using a hashmap of values....so i would ask you to use requestParameterValues